# Progress Bar - HTML5 - Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, progress-bar, vendor-prefix

I created a progress bar using HTML5 .
However I am using a transition effect that only works on Chrome, Opera and Safari. But isn't it working in Firefox?

This is my progress bar -> https://codepen.io/thadeucesario/pen/KKdWKdr

Do you know how I can fix it?

For these browsers I'm using:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
     background: #0b366f;
     -webkit-transition : width .5s ease;
     -moz-transition : width .5s ease;
     -o-transition : width .5s ease;
     transition : width .5s ease;
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing , for two .
I used the 'width' of the innermost , as if it were the progress value.
Now it worked perfectly on all browsers.

Particularly, I was unable to solve the problem with vendor prefix.